# virtual folders with mongoDB logic

Tags: php, mongodb

Need a bit of logic help. I have a folder I'll be uploading alot of files to via http/php/post. I'm going to index them into a collection in MongoDB when they upload. I need to organize the files into different folders, in reality there will be no folders, but when someone will be viewing the interface I'll be putting together it will look like a file tree. I'll also be setting permissions to the virtual folders. I've been thinking over and over of how to index the files into virtual folders into a Mongo Collection, where I get stuck is assigning permissions to each user. I was thinking of indexing a file and virtual folders like this(sorry for the long code, just trying to give you an idea of how deep the file tree will go):

```
$collection->insert(array(
    '_id' => new MongoID(),
    'type' => 'folder',
    'folderOrFileNameAndLocation' => 'products'
));
$collection->insert(array(
    '_id' => new MongoID(),
    'type' => 'folder',
    'folderOrFileNameAndLocation' => 'products/device'
));
$collection->insert(array(
        '_id' => new MongoID(),
        'type' => 'folder',
        'folderOrFileNameAndLocation' => 'products/device/manuals'
    ));

$collection->insert(array(
        '_id' => new MongoID(),
        'type' => 'file',
        'fileName' => 'theManual.pdf',
        'location' => 'products/device/manuals/'
    ));
```

My problem is how to assign permissions to folders for each user when I add a user, here's what I was thinking

```
$collection->insert(array(
        '_id' => new MongoID(),
        'username' => 'Joe',
        'password' => '1234', //will obviously be one way hashed
        //STORE AS A STRING
        'permissibleFolders' => 'products/device/manuals/, software/latest/'
    ));

    //OR SHOULD I DO IT THIS WAY???

    $collection->insert(array(
        '_id' => new MongoID(),
        'username' => 'Joe',
        'password' => '1234', //will obviously be one way hashed
        'permissibleFolders' => array(
            //DO I HAVE TO SET A KEY FOR THIS OR CAN I JUST ADD THEM IN?
            products/device/manuals/,
            software/latest/
        )
    ));
```

Now by doing it that way, how would I query the folders allocated to the user? This is what I was thinking, but how do I query the last part? I can make it work with a nested query, but that's something I try to never do.

```
$pulledData = $collection->find(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
        $doesExist = $pulledData -> count();
        if($doesExist == 1){
            logUserInAndStuff();
            foreach($pulledData as $row){
                $accessibleFolders = $row['permissibleFolders'];
            }
            //HOW DO I MAKE THIS QUERY THE PROPER FOLDERS?
            $pulledData = $collection->find(array('folderNameAndLocation'=>$accessibleFolders));

        }
```

Sorry if my logic is stupid, I just have very limited "pull" with the server and what I'm allowed to do. I was given nothing and expected to pull through with something grand. Any better way of doing this that someone could help me come up with would be awesome! I'm pretty new to noSQL, I maybe thinking too much structure lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a list of allowed users to each file system object

Adding permissions for a user is easy

```
db.collection.update({folderOrFileNameAndLocation : 'products'}, {$push: {allowedUsers: 'Joe'}})
```

Removing users is easy

```
db.collection.update({folderOrFileNameAndLocation : 'products'}, {$pull: {allowedUsers: 'Joe'}})
```

Checking permissions is easy

```
db.collection.find({folderOrFileNameAndLocation : 'products', allowedUsers : 'Joe'})
```

And listing everything accessible to the user is easy

```
db.collection.find({allowedUsers: 'Joe'}, {folderOrFileNameAndLocation: 1, _id: 0})
```

One thing that you might find helpful is to build out your files and folders as a tree as opposed to having the location be a string.  So you'll have

```
$collection->insert(array(
    '_id' => new MongoID(),
    'type' => 'folder',
    'folderOrFileName' => 'products'
));
```

Then to create a subfolder:

```
$collection->find(array('folderOrFileName' => 'products'));
$collection->insert(array(
    '_id' => new MongoID(),
    'type' => 'folder',
    'folderOrFileName' => 'device',
    'parent' => $collection['_id']
));
```

There are pluses and minuses to that structure; depending on what else you need to support you might find your way or the tree way easier.  But I would definitely recommend assigning user names to folders instead of vice versa.